Interdependency between k8s pods
I have two deployments, one for my web app and one for the api backend.
When the API changes I need a new web client version, otherwise the web client will error out because of an incompatible api client.
on the order hand, I can't deploy the web client before the new backend, or I'll get the same error.
How can I ensure both deployments get published to the web at the same time? Should I use a single deployment configuration with multiple containers?

Try to avoid making changes like this.  The other related problem is that end users' browsers will still have copies of the old application, either actually running or in their cache, and even if you update the client code on the server side, your end users will still hit the compatibility problems.  (Neither this statement nor the problem are especially Kubernetes-specific.)

You cannot break APIs, you can only expand, and later deprecate them when the API has no consumers.
